# index of array with smarty variables is not working

Tags: php, smarty3, smarty2

I have created array variable in .php file

like

```
$arImagePath[TE] = 'XYZ';
```

in my .tpl 
`{$carnumber}` is giving 'T' and `{$carinitial}` is giving 'E'.

I am trying to get value 'XYZ' as follows

```
{$arImagePath[{$carnumber}+{$carinitial}]}
```

I tried many combination still unavailable to get array value.

smarty version -2.6.26

Hoping for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [documentation](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.syntax.variables.tpl) (Smarty v2) :

> {$foo[bar]}   <-- syntax only valid in a section loop, see {section}

So, if you want to access the array variable directly and you are not in a loop, you have to do it this way:

> {$foo.bar}    <-- display the "bar" key value of an array, similar to
>   PHP $foo['bar']

Now, to archive what you need:

```
// This assignment could change dynamically
{assing var="carnumber" value="T"}
{assing var="carinitial" value="E"}
// For the sake of clarity, I'm going to concat in one variable the above assignments
{assing var="index" value=$carnumber|cat:$carinitial}

//Now access the array at the index we need
{$arImagePath.$index} // XYZ
```